# what error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

what is this error meaning:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near times new roman; font-size: x-large; color: #a67859;> at line 1

query

```
 update page set en_title = 'Team', 
  en_content = ' Jasmine Low Sales & Marketing Manager (Singapore) ', image_1 = 'Shirley.jpg',

image_2 = 'Jessica.jpg', keyword = 'test', description = '' where id_page = '3'

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'times new roman'; font-size: x-large;">Cheryl Koh
```

Comment: please post the query

Comment: Please add your SQL query in the question too!

Comment: its a line 1 check it what's there.

Comment: Probably just wrong or missing quotes...

Comment: I am submit a form with text input through ck-editor when i submit data above sql error showing. plz give me solution

Comment: update page set en_title = 'Team', en_content = '', image_1 = 'Shirley.jpg', image_2 = 'Jessica.jpg', keyword = 'test', description = '' where id_page = '3'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'times new roman'; font-size: x-large;">Cheryl Koh

Comment: update page set en_title = 'Team', en_content = '  

Jasmine Low

Sales & Marketing Manager (Singapore)


', image_1 = 'Shirley.jpg', image_2 = 'Jessica.jpg', keyword = 'test', description = '' where id_page = '3'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'times new roman'; font-size: x-large;">Cheryl Koh

Answer (score 0):

Your query :

```
update page
set en_title = 'Team',
    en_content = ' Jasmine Low Sales & Marketing Manager (Singapore) ',
    image_1 = 'Shirley.jpg',
    image_2 = 'Jessica.jpg',
    keyword = 'test',
    description = ''
where id_page = '3'
```

is correct but your SQL script or how you run your SQL script contains the error.

If your error comes from the en_content containing the phrase "'times new roman'; font-size: x-large;" then you should better use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) instead of concatenating arbitrary string with your SQL (which could cause SQL injection by the way).

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'update page
set en_title = ?,
    en_content = ?,
    image_1 = ?,
    image_2 = ?,
    keyword = ?,
    description = ?
where id_page = ?';

set @en_title = 'Team';
set @en_content = ' Jasmine Low Sales & Marketing Manager (Singapore) ';
set @image_1 = 'Shirley.jpg';
set @image_2 = 'Jessica.jpg';
set @keyword = 'test';
set @description = '';
set @id_page = '3';

EXECUTE stmt1 USING @en_title, @en_content, @image_1, @image_2, @keyword, @description, @id_page;
```

Comment: In above query en_content's field data is showing simple text not showing full content here, but en_content  field's HTML data comes from ck-editor.